# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Desktop

Tags: windows-7, ssl, visual-studio, tls, visual-studio-2013

I am facing a small problem .. unintentionally uninstalled the `NuGet Package` tool from my Visual Studio 2013 where I use it to install frameworks, libraries, among others .. however when trying to reinstall it, it presents the following protocol error ..

[image]

By clicking the **Download** button

[image]

I know that this refers to a protocol and certificate problem, because in my applications where I use the WebRequest and HttpWebRequest functions, it is always necessary to change the protocol to TLS, as it returns an error in which the request was unable to complete the call in SSL protocol, however I change to version TLS 1.2 and the request is completed successfully!

#### OBS

I do not know if such a problem requires an update with *Windows Update*, as I have searched everywhere, forums, websites, but I have not had any success. My **Windows 7** version is **Home Premium Service Pack 1**

Comment: You have installed all Visual Studio 2013 updates?

Comment: Try [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59030708/165358) (note well the comment below the answer).